# How to print across subnets with CUPS?

Tags: ubuntu, subnet, printing, cups

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04. I am printing from a Non-AirPrint Printer to iPads, which is why im using cups. I can find the printer if I'm on the same vlan as the server. I need to be able to find and print from different vlans. i have read many forums and none have solved my issue. thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you are printing from the iPads? Your question says you are printing to iPads, which is completely backward; iPads aren't printers. Also, where does the Ubuntu server fit in here? Do you mean that it's the print server for the printer?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CUPS. You need routing between the networks in order to communicate between the networks.